# Redis starts, is ready to accept connections, but commands does not works

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I started redis on Ubuntu using redis-server:
[image]

127.0.0.1:6379> doesn't appear on the last line and no command works. How to fix this?

I tryed to enter redis-cli, ping. Not working:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the `redis-server` process is running using the `ps` command?  If it isn't there will be nothing for `redis-cli` to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check if Redis server is running collecting:

`ps axufwww | grep 'redis'`

- test the connection  to Redis running:

`echo "ping" | redis-cli`

Comment: redis is running. 
echo "ping" | redis-cli worked for me